# ¿Puedo enviar varios FormData dentro de un array a travez de ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter-3

Saludo a todos. Cuento con la siguiente inquietud.
Tengo el siguiente código por Javascript donde capturo datos de diferentes inputs, es decir que lo que debo realizar es recorrer todos los inputs y guardarlos al hacer click en un solo botón.

```
function guardar() {
var id = $("#id").val()
var datos = new FormData();
var arr = new Array();  
for(var i = 0; i < totalfilas; i++) {       
    if ($('#check' + i).is(':checked')) {
        var inputTipo = $("#file-1" + i).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
        var inputprop = $('#file-1' + i).prop('files')[0];
        datos.append('Revisor', $('#usuario' + i).val())
        datos.append('Observaciones', $('#obs' + i).val())
        datos.append('Archivos', CargaArchivos(inputTipo, inputprop))
        arr.push(datos)
    }
}
$.ajax({
    url: 'Planificacion/guardar/' + id,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    data: {'array': arr}
})
}
```

El ciclo for es el que me ayuda a recorrer todos los inputs que estoy listando, los identifica y ayuda a obtener su valor.
Al enviar yo estos datos por el data: del ajax estos llegan a mi controlador (Debo resaltar que utilizo codeigniter 3)

```
public function guardar($id){
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
        $arreglo = $this->input->post('array');
        foreach($arreglo as $array){
            echo $array;
        }           
    }
 }
```

Al debuggear el controlador me doy cuenta que la variable $arreglo está llegando en null pero cuando debuggeo el js me doy cuenta que si la variable arr y guarda los FormData().

Para ser mas claro con respecto a mi objetivo quisiera enviar todos los datos del formulario por un arreglo para poder recorrerlos en php y así poder guardarlos.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro del ciclo estás agregando en `arr` todo el contenido de `formData` en cada iteración y, de hecho, según [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects):

> Los objetos FormData le permiten compilar un conjunto de pares clave/valor para enviar mediante XMLHttpRequest. Están destinados principalmente para el envío de los datos del formulario...

No necesitas (ni debes) insertar el objeto dentro de un arreglo u objeto, sino usarlo directamente, porque los datos ya están preparados:

```
function guardar() {
    let id = $("#id").val();
    let datos = new FormData();
    // let arr = new Array();  // No necesitas este arreglo
    for(var i = 0; i < totalfilas; i++) {
        if ($('#check' + i).is(':checked')) {
            let inputTipo = $("#file-1" + i).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
            let inputprop = $('#file-1' + i).prop('files')[0];

            // Tus datos son arreglos, agrega corchetes a los nombres
            datos.append('Revisor[]', $('#usuario' + i).val());
            datos.append('Observaciones[]', $('#obs' + i).val());

            // CargaArchivos debe devolver una lista de archivos (uno o más)
            // datos.append('Archivos[]', CargaArchivos(inputTipo, inputprop));

            // Sería más adecuado agregarlo directamente
            datos.append('Archivos[]', inputprop);

            // arr.push(datos); // Esto no es necesario
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Planificacion/guardar/' + id,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: datos // Envía solo el formData
    });
}
```

Ahora, en PHP debes tener en cuenta que cada campo se recibe como arreglo independiente, pero todos con la misma cantidad de elementos y mismo índice:

```
// Ejemplo para obtener cada arreglo
$revisor = $this->input->post('Revisor');
$observa = $this->input->post('Observaciones');

// Los archivos se manejan de diferente forma
// Primero debes configurar e instanciar la clase Upload

// Recorrer y usar mismo índice para todos (puede ser foreach o for)
for($i = 0; i < count($revisor); $i++) {
    // Obtener cada elemento:
    echo "<p>Revisor: {$revisor[$i]}<br>";
    echo "Observaciones: {$observa[$i]}</p>";
    // Aquí debes usar la clase Upload para analizar el archivo y subirlo
}
```

Los archivos se deben manejar de otra forma. Desconozco Codeigniter y deberás buscar más información al respecto, tal vez comenzando por la clase [Upload](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: Probando un poco con mi código me di cuenta que la razón por la que enviaba mi data del ajax en nulo al php era porque en ese ajax utilizaba 2 propiedades que son necesarias para enviar variables tipo FormData() que vendría siendo contentType: false,
processData: false. al quitar esto ya enviaba datos a mi php

Comment: Utilicé otra manera de enviar los datos, lo que hice fue crear un objeto en el ciclo for del js para que guardara los datos en el arraglo y luego acabara el ciclo los mandaba en ajax en el data. Esto se me hacía mas facil para manipular los datos en el php. Lo que no entiendo de tu respuesta es el porqué no debo insertar objetos en un arreglo.

Comment: @Sairento, porque `formData` ya preparó los datos para ser enviados por AJAX, no necesitas meterlo en un arreglo y, mucho menos, que cada elemento del arreglo sea el mismo objeto.